# two loops inside one single table tr

Tags: python, html, angularjs, django

Hi I have the following code for one of my table:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h2 align="center">Severity</h2>
        <table class="table table-hover paleblue">
            <tr style="background-color: #eb0000; color:white">
                <th width="10px">Rank</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Criteria</th>
            </tr>
            {%verbatim%}
                <tr ng-repeat="s in siverity track by $index">
                    <td>
                        {{$index+1}}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div ng-repeat="s in siverity" class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
                         {{s}}<br>
                        <textarea class="form-control">{{s}}</textarea>
                         </div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div ng-repeat="c in criteria" class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
                           {{c}}<br>
                        <textarea class="form-control">{{c}}</textarea>
                         </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {%endverbatim%}
        </table>
    </div>
```

script:

```
$scope.siverity = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$scope.criteria = ['D', 'E', 'F'];
```

The problem with the html is, it is actually creating 3 tds inside the tr instead of 1. How can I fix that so that i will have a table with rank 1 and two tds corresponding to that? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: why use DIV tag in table? it is wrong.

Comment: because the values are actually dynamic

Comment: lets say, if i remove all the div, i will get my result, but the value for criteria is from another list, how can i loop that so that criteria will have the value?

Comment: instead of DIV use span.

Comment: basically the criteria is from a different list. I want to nest it inside the main for loop. Thats the main concern

Comment: or use another table in td.

Comment: Its nothing about using span or div. Its about how can I make another loop inside my tr. By the way span give me same result as div

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want your table to look like?

Comment: Hi evergreen, updated

Comment: Now i can able to display the tds (Or table as shown in the question. But the value is not able to display.)

Comment: Because its a different list (need a different for loop as per the $scope.criteria = ['D', 'E', 'F'];)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all I would change the way you keep your data in $scope.
If you'd have something like

```
$scope.ranks = [{
    id: 1,
    siverity: 'A',
    criteria: 'D'
}, {
    id: 2,
    siverity: 'B',
    criteria: 'E'
}, {
    id: 3,
    siverity: 'C',
    criteria: 'F'
}];
```

you could have your template to be:

```
{%verbatim%}
<tr ng-repeat="rank in ranks">
  <td>
    {{rank.id}}
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
     {{rank.siverity}}<br>
    <textarea class="form-control">{{rank.siverity}}</textarea>
     </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
       {{rank.criteria}}<br>
    <textarea class="form-control">{{rank.criteria}}</textarea>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
{%endverbatim%}
```

If for whatever reason you have to keep the $scope as it is, you could change your template like so:

```
{%verbatim%}
<tr ng-repeat="s in siverity track by $index">
  <td>
    {{$index}}
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
     {{s}}<br>
    <textarea class="form-control">{{s}}</textarea>
     </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
       {{criteria[$index]}}<br>
    <textarea class="form-control">{{criteria[$index]}}</textarea>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
{%endverbatim%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few changes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in siverity track by $index">
        <td>
          {{$index+1}}
        </td>
        <td>
           <div ng-repeat="s in siverity" class="col-md-12" style="height:100px"
```

you don't need the above line since you already iterating siverity

```
            {{s}}<br>
             <textarea class="form-control">{{s}}</textarea>
           </div>
      </td>

      <td>
         <div ng-repeat="c in criteria" class="col-md-12" style="height:100px">
          {{c}}<br>
              <textarea class="form-control">{{c}}</textarea>
          </div>
      </td>
</tr>
```